# Running a Flutter app with firebase_auth from a different machine in debug mode causes an Invalid_cert_Hash

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used firebase_auth with github_sign_in provider to authenticate my users. I have added the debug sha-1 and sha-256 keys to the firebase console. The app seems to be work on my local machine, however when i clone the repo to a new machine and add the same google-services.json file I am getting the following error:

```
D/EGL_emulation(22226): app_time_stats: avg=3526.14ms min=22.24ms max=13948.25ms count=4
W/System  (22226): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth(22226): [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
D/EGL_emulation(22226): app_time_stats: avg=104.52ms min=6.82ms max=4039.29ms count=47
```

Is this the intended behavior or am I making a mistake somewhere. Do I have to add debug sha-1 and sha-256 from every device in order for it to work without any issue ?

firebase auth package version used:
[4.6.1](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/changelog)

flutter doctor -v :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.10.1 on channel stable at /Users/USER_NAME/fvm/versions/3.10.1
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d3d8effc68 (5 days ago), 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
    • Engine revision b4fb11214d
    • Dart version 3.0.1
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.64.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.126

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a new set of SHA-1 and SHA-256 Debug keys for each machine that you run your code on. Remember to re-download the google-services.json file after adding the new keys and replace the one already in your project